# Is there a list somewhere of video cards that support GPGPU programming?

Tags: gpgpu, parallel-processing, nvidia

Mine is a "NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GS" and everywhere I've searched I can only find "9500 GT" ... does that mean the 9500 GS does not support any GPGPU language such as CUDA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the official list :

http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_learn_products.html

Your 9500GS isn't listed so I'd say no ... but that's trivial to test, just download the sdk and run the example app ...

Answer (score 1):

Is that a 9500M GS? If so, it has CUDA support
http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_9500m_gs_us.html

All post-G80 GPUs should have CUDA support